# Is there any way to train a neural network without using gradients?

Tags: neural-networks, training, reference-request, stochastic-gradient-descent

The only algorithm I know for updation of weights of a neural network is based on gradients. The update equation can be roughly written as

$$w \leftarrow w - \nabla_{w}L$$

where $\nabla_{w}L$ is the gradient of loss function with respect to weights.

Are there any learning algorithms for updating weights in neural networks that does not use gradients?

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

A prominent class of "gradient-free" algorithms in ML world is known as *Evolution Strategies (ES)*. [Evolutionary Algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_computation), although existed for a long time, only a few have shown to scale well.

Recently, the research group OpenAI managed to train Deep RL models with a specific variant of ES (with careful engineering). You can read [this paper](https://openai.com/blog/evolution-strategies/). [This blog](https://blog.otoro.net/2017/10/29/visual-evolution-strategies/) by David Ha provides a starting point if you want to learn about ES and its modern derivatives.